# Generate Typescript from swagger.json file on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, typescript, nswag

I am using the NSwag NPM module [Git repo here](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) to generate Typescript code for my Angular application from a swagger.json file yet it looks like the generated code is outdated. I would like to generated client code to use Observables as opposed to Promises and the new HttpClient module. Is there a config/settings file I can put together to generate updated code?